# UWP BLE stops notifications when using internal Bluetooth

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE sensor that sends data at a frequency of 100Hz and I've developed an UWP application to receive this data. I'm having a weird issue where after a couple of seconds of everything working fine, I stop receiving notifications for new data.

Now, I say it's weird because this happens when I'm using the laptop's internal Bluetooth but not when using a Bluetooth dongle. When using the dongle it works fine and never stops. Both internal Bluetooth and dongle drivers are updated to the latest version Windows can find.

As soon as the notification stops the sensor disconnects.

The sensor is based on the Nordic nRF52832 SoC.

Now a bit of information about my code:

- I have a Sensor.cs class in which I handle the connection and the streaming of the data.
- I'm using `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` in order to find the sensor.
- The `GattCharacteristic`'s are private members of the Sensor class.
- I subscribe to notifications by calling:

```
await _gattDataSensorsCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
   GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
```

The application doesn't do anything fancy. Just connects to the sensor, starts the streaming and prints the data.

I've done quite a research and couldn't find anything similar. I've found posts about notifications stopping because the object was taken away by the GC, the characteristics were local variables instead of class members or calls weren't awaited.

Why does this happen?

### 1st edit

@Emil I'm sorry, my fault for not mentioning that as soon as the notifications stop, the sensor disconnects. I'm editing the question to mention that as well as it's something relevant. Anyway I'm trying what you mention asap.

@GrooverFromHolland That option was checked. I've tried unchecking that option on a couple of computers but sadly, unchecking it only makes the code last a few seconds longer.

@Nico Zhu - MSFT I've followed the link you posted and read the doc also went to my sensor's manual to double check if the characteristic allows Notify and it does, it does allow Read and Notify. I also do the same thing `characteristic.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;` as it's mentioned in the doc.

About the sensor disconnecting when the notifications stop/the valuechanged stops firing. I have to add that on my MainWindow, the sensor object is a member class and it isn't disposed at any moment. So it doesn't make sense that the GC takes the object away, right?

### 2nd edit

I've tried the code I'm using with both the laptop plugged and unplugged to a power source and it's always set to max performance. The code I'm using can be found here: [link](https://github.com/PauDC864/simpletransmission)

### 3rd edit

Following @Emil 's  recommendations I was finally able to scan the traffic. Tried to understand what the pcap file generated by USBPcap, but I simply don't understand. I've tried the issue with 2 sensors and the disconnect/notification stop pattern looks different for each sensor.
I've made a Dropbox folder containing the two pcap files: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r405q409okuh6sa/AACpE9aXlFM6DwASmE2RYfXla?dl=0)

From what I understood, in the file "ble-FE592382586F.pcap" the interesting line No are: 12647 and 12681. It says the source is the controller and the destination is host. Is the controller the laptop's bluetooth driver?

Comment: Have you used a BLE sniffer to see if the packets are really sent over the air? You should also use USBPcap with Wireshark to inspect the HCI packets if the notifications are present.

Comment: In Windows  Device Manager check  Bluetooth device properties. If there is a Power Management tab, make sure "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is unchecked.

Comment: Please check this document [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client#subscribing-for-notifications). *Make sure the characteristic supports either Indicate or Notify (check the characteristic properties to make sure).* because most GATT transactions would rather conserve power rather than be extremely reliable. In any case, all of that is handled at the controller layer so the app does not get involved.

Comment: @Emil Thanks for the tip I'm gonna try it as soon as I rememer how to use Wireshark, it's been a while since I've used it. Also, I've edited the question with further information on the issue, because I've missed some key information.

Comment: @GrooverFromHolland  Thanks for your reply, that option was checked. I've tried uncheking that option on a couple of computers but sadly, unchecking it only makes the code last a few seconds longer. I've also edited the question because relevant information was missing.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for the tip, I've followed the link you posted and read the doc also went to my sensor's manual to double check if the characteristic allows Notify and it does, it does allow Read and Notify. I've also edited the question becase relevant information was missing

Comment: Yep, your comment is correct, could you share a sample that could reproduce this issue, i will test base on that. And have you tried to test with external power and set the power model as performance for your labtop?

Comment: What's the disconnect reason? Is it "terminated by local/remote device" or "connection timeout" or anything else?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes, the code was tried both with the laptop plugged and unplugged and always to max performance. And for the sample, I've uploaded this repo with the code I'm using that works perfectly with the bt dongle: [link](https://github.com/PauDC864/simpletransmission) I'm going to edit the question to add this

Comment: @Emil I don't know. It's not terminated by the app because I'm only calling disconnect in case I'm not getting any characteristics from the sensor. And it's not connection timeout because I get to stream data for a small amout of time, and before streaming data the connection timeout timer is stopped. I've updated the question with an answer to a previous comment linking a repo with the code I'm using if you want to check it. Not asking you to fix my code, I'm doing it to provide more information. I'm really grateful to you and the other for taking your time and helping me out.

Comment: If you use USBPcap/Wireshark to scan the hci traffic, you will see which device initiated the disconnection (or if the link was dropped due to connection timeout). That would be a good start to see where the problem lies.

Comment: @PauDC, I checked your code, it is perfect, but I have no the specific device that matched password and mac id, so I could not finish the test. Your problem is very strange, and I will escalate this issue.

Comment: @Emil I was finally able to scan the traffic using the tool you said, thank you. I didn't understand well the information it provided. I've updated the question with a 3rd edit with the things I saw, and what I understood.

Answer (score 1):

Controller means the bluetooth chip (inside or outside the computer) and host is the main cpu. They talk with each other over usb. At packet 12681 in the first file, the disconnect reason is Connection Timeout (0x08). This means the connection was dropped unexpectedly (radio interference/bad signal?). At packet 613 in the other file, we have the same situation. A difference is that in only in the second file, there was a new attempt to reconnect the device.

Since you do not use bonding, you must make sure to re-write the client characteristic configuration descriptor upon every new connection. It doesn't seem like you do this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the pcap files, I've went through them and now I know where to look at for future issues. Now, about rewriting the CCCD on every new connection, I understand that when connecting and finding the characteristics once find the charateristic I want to get notifications from, I must call 
`await _gattDataSensorsCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                                    GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);`
I've tried this and it's still  happening

Comment: Do you see that it re-connects? If so, could you post a new log?

Comment: I've uploaded a new log to the same link/folder. This log's code has what I commented on the previous comment. In this new log I see that the desconnection occurs at line 2265. then in line 2267 the host tells the controller to enable LE scanning. From this point I've left the application running for a few minutes, but I don't see it reconnected or at least tried to.

Comment: It actually tells to disable scanning (if you examine the "scan enable" field). It also removes the device from the white list, so apparently Windows has decided to not reconnect. Maybe someone at Microsoft could answer why.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar - what I discovered was that the *GattCharacteristic* (the object you call WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync on) was getting GCed - as soon as I added that to a class-wide variable (I made a Dictionary of all the characteristics I was tracking), my notifications kept coming